# Numpy - FutureWarning: arrays to stack must be passed as a sequence as type such as list or tuple

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to know how to solve this problem with np.vstack

> FutureWarning: arrays to stack must be passed as a "sequence" type such as list or tuple. Support for non-sequence iterables such as generators is deprecated as of NumPy 1.16 and will raise an error in the future.
> a = np.vstack({tuple(row) for row in b})

```
def calc_cov_beta4(xi, yi, noise, fu, f_para, value_set, j, k):
   def get_covariance_function4_std(x, y, data, noise, delta, fu, f_para, filenamei, ncore):
    rms_data1 = 3 * np.sqrt(np.sum(data[:,0]**2) / float(len(data)))
    rms_data2 = 3 * np.sqrt(np.sum(data[:,1]**2) / float(len(data)))
    if len(np.where(abs(data[:,0]) > rms_data1)[0]) > 0:
        data[:,0] = data[np.where(abs(data[:,0]) <= rms_data1)[0],0]
        x = x[np.where(abs(data[:,0]) <= rms_data1)[0]]
        y = y[np.where(abs(data[:,0]) <= rms_data1)[0]]
        data[:,1] = data[np.where(abs(data[:,0]) <= rms_data1)[0],1]
        noise[:,0] = noise[np.where(abs(data[:,0]) <= rms_data1)[0],0]
        noise[:,1] = noise[np.where(abs(data[:,0]) <= rms_data1)[0],1]
        print('Outlier identified and removed')
    if len(np.where(abs(data[:,1]) > rms_data2)[0]) > 0:
        data[:,1] = data[np.where(abs(data[:,1]) <= rms_data2)[0],1]
        x = x[np.where(abs(data[:,1]) <= rms_data2)[0]]
        y = y[np.where(abs(data[:,1]) <= rms_data2)[0]]
        data[:,0] = data[np.where(abs(data[:,1]) <= rms_data2)[0],0]
        noise[:,0] = noise[np.where(abs(data[:,1]) <= rms_data2)[0],0]
        noise[:,1] = noise[np.where(abs(data[:,1]) <= rms_data2)[0],1]
        print('Outlier identified and removed')
    
    dmax = np.degrees(g.inv(np.amin(x), np.amin(y), np.amax(x), np.amax(y))[2] / float(R))
    ddata_dict = {}
    ddata_dict[0, 0] = np.c_[np.linspace(0, len(x) - 1, len(x)).astype(int), np.linspace(0, len(x) - 1, len(x)).astype(int)]
    for k in xrange(1, int(np.ceil(dmax / delta))):
        a = []
        if k == 1:
            delta_min = 0
            delta_max = delta
        else:
            delta_min = (2 * k - 3) * delta
            delta_max = (2 * k - 1) * delta
        for i, j in itertools.product(xrange(len(x)), xrange(len(x))):
            if i != j:
                dij = np.degrees(g.inv(x[i], y[i], x[j], y[j])[2] / float(R))
                if delta_min < dij <= delta_max:
                    a.append([i, j])
        if (k > 30) and (len(a) < np.round(len(data), -1 * (len(str(len(data))) - 1)) * 5):
            break
        if (k <= 30) and (len(a) <= (len(x) * 2.)):
            continue
        if len(a) > 30:
            a = np.asarray(a)
            indices = np.argsort(a, axis=1)
            b = np.array([a[i,indices[i]] for i in xrange(len(indices))])
            a = np.vstack({tuple(row) for row in b})
            ddata_dict[delta_min, delta_max] = a
        
    li_dict = {}
    for i in xrange(len(ddata_dict.keys())):
        li = []
        for j in xrange(len(ddata_dict.values()[i])):
            pt1 = ddata_dict.values()[i][j][0]
            pt2 = ddata_dict.values()[i][j][1]
            li.append([pt1, pt2, 0, 0, 'e', 'e'])
            li.append([pt1, pt2, 1, 1, 'n', 'n'])
            if (pt1 != pt2) and (float('%.3f'%(x[pt1])) != float('%.3f'%(x[pt2]))):
                li.append([pt1, pt2, 0, 1, 'e', 'n'])
                li.append([pt1, pt2, 1, 0, 'n', 'e'])
        li_dict[ddata_dict.keys()[i]] = np.asarray(li)
```

Comment: Can you pare this down to a minimal example (i.e., one that has enough of the equations to do the vstack call and nothing more)?  I suspect it's complaining about the set comprehension `{tuple(row) for row in b}` but I cannot confirm it without more information.  I also don't have a 2.7 system to test it on, but I think the warning is coming from NumPy itself.

Comment: This problem does not depend on your Python version. As a side note, please update to Python 3.x. It has been revised all the way up to 3.10 now, with 3.11 in the pipeline. 2.7 has not been supported for more than two years. In terms of how outdated it is, it is comparable to using Windows 7 as your operating system.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I started the train for you.